# ReportViewer control generates blank report data on specific reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, reporting-services, webforms

I have been playing around the Azure virtual machines and have setup successfully a Web Application VM and an Azure Database/ReportServer 2014 VM .

My current build works fine on all browser and am able to generate reports locally if I am to connect to my local ReportServer(MSRS12).

However, If I point it to the Azure ReportServer(MSRS12), I am unable to generate specific reports and only returns a blank report data.

Currently I have two set of reports. First is the report with a static parameters namely just the year. This report is generated normally.

Second reports are the one that is dynamically mapped parameters. Theses reports only returns blank report data with parameter control still active.

Upon checking the Report Server Execution Logs on the database, I found out that The first report were executed just fine.

The second reports are executing normally but returns a blank report data with very short loading times. Normally the reports take about 1-3 minutes to render.

Checking again the Report Server Execution Logs on the database, second report were not executed at all. Not even a record of a failure of execution.

My current setup in Azure Database/ReportServer are just the default and have not changed anything regarding the security aside from the inbound rules to allow access to SQL traffics.

Site is currently done in asp.net, and code is in C#.

So far I have done the following:

Updated ReportViewer dlls.

set AsyncRendering = false

set element.style.overflow = "visible"